# Difficulty scraping a table from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been trying to fetch tabular content from this [webpage](https://cityofdavid.secure.force.com/?productId=01t0600000AE2dR&lang=en_us) using requests module. However, when I execute the script below, I get something gibberish other than the results available in that table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://cityofdavid.secure.force.com/?productId=01t0600000AE2dR&lang=en_us'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    resp = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("table.table > tbody > tr"):
        data = [i.text for i in item.select("td")]
        print(data)
```

Current result:

```
["{{timeForTour.TourStartTime__c | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' : '200'}}", '{{timeForTour.TourStartHour__c }}', '{{timeForTour.EndTime__c}}', '{{timeForTour.Number_Of_Participants_Left__c}}', '\nSelect\n\n']
['{{price.Name}}', '{{price.Field1__c}}', '\n\n\n', '{{(price.quantity)? price.Field1__c*price.quantity:0}}', 'NIS']
['{{item.Name}}', '{{item.Field1__c}}', '{{item.quantity}}', '{{item.quantity*item.Field1__c}}', 'NIS']
```

Expected result (truncated):

```
24/01/2022  10:00   11:00   15
24/01/2022  12:00   13:00   15
24/01/2022  14:00   15:00   15
24/01/2022  16:00   17:00   15
```

PS This is the [landing page](https://www.cityofdavid.org.il/en/tours/city-david/city-david-vr) from where I clicked the `book a tour` button to get the link in my above request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get that data in the page resource since it is loaded dynamically. If you look into the resource page you can see there is no data which you require.
[image: Screenshot of the table you are referring to]

You can get your required data from the API call as a JSON object.Copy the curl command and import it in Postman and use the code in your script.
[image]

In the below screenshot you can see the actual data you wanted.
[image]

**Edited** This will give the expected result.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://cityofdavid.secure.force.com/apexremote"

payload = json.dumps([
  {
    "action": "OrderTourController",
    "method": "getAllTimeForTour",
    "data": [
      "01t0600000AE2dR",
      "2022-1-24 12:18:4",
      0,
      "en_us"
    ],
    "type": "rpc",
    "tid": 3,
    "ctx": {
      "csrf": "VmpFPSxNakF5TWkwd01TMHlOMVF3TmpvME9Eb3dNeTQ1TlRaYSxJZExXMldWSU1neGFlWDdFb01YNi1ULE1XTmpaV1F4",
      "vid": "06624000003gGO2",
      "ns": "",
      "ver": 35
    }
  }
])
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'Referer': 'https://cityofdavid.secure.force.com/?productId=01t0600000AE2dR&lang=en_us&_ga=2.113284295.1937905009.1643006618-1494711041.1643006618',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)




json_result=json.loads(json.loads(response.text)[0]['result'])
for res in json_result:
    print(res['TourStartTime__c'], res['TourStartHour__c'] ,res['EndTime__c'],res['MaxNumerOfParticipants__c'])
```

**Output**

```
2022-01-25T08:00:00.000+0000 10:00 11:00 15
2022-01-25T10:00:00.000+0000 12:00 13:00 15
2022-01-25T12:00:00.000+0000 14:00 15:00 15
2022-01-25T14:00:00.000+0000 16:00 17:00 15
2022-01-26T08:00:00.000+0000 10:00 11:00 15
2022-01-26T10:00:00.000+0000 12:00 13:00 15
2022-01-26T12:00:00.000+0000 14:00 15:00 15
2022-01-26T14:00:00.000+0000 16:00 17:00 15
2022-01-27T08:00:00.000+0000 10:00 11:00 15
2022-01-27T10:00:00.000+0000 12:00 13:00 15
2022-01-27T12:00:00.000+0000 14:00 15:00 15
2022-01-27T14:00:00.000+0000 16:00 17:00 15
2022-01-30T08:00:00.000+0000 10:00 11:00 15
2022-01-30T10:00:00.000+0000 12:00 13:00 15
2022-01-30T12:00:00.000+0000 14:00 15:00 15
2022-01-30T14:00:00.000+0000 16:00 17:00 15
2022-01-31T08:00:00.000+0000 10:00 11:00 15
2022-01-31T10:00:00.000+0000 12:00 13:00 15
2022-01-31T12:00:00.000+0000 14:00 15:00 15
2022-01-31T14:00:00.000+0000 16:00 17:00 15
```

Comment: Although this is a way to get your hands on the data, it doesn't really answer the question and certainly doesn't provide a way to automate scraping the data, as a lot of manual interaction is required?

Comment: You can use the same request in the script to get the data and process further. Using selenium will certainly increase the time. It is easier to get the data this way. Incase if you don't know how to use it please ask.

Comment: Are you addressing me or OP, @manishshetty? I don't see how manually using a browser and a third-party tool would make a process faster or easier than a fully automated procedure as outlined in the script that uses `selenium` - a complete run only takes about 2-3 seconds, so I fail to see how you'd beat that? Of course the API call alone will be faster, but that's assuming the session information in the curl URL will remain valid over time, which seems unlikely.

Comment: In this case it requires only 'Referer'  in the Headers which can remain constant. Third party tools used are just to demonstrate the process. If he only needs those data he doesn't even need to load the page. 
Also if he wants to run the scraper in some other system he has to setup selenium there.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is the most common `BeautifulSoup` question, but a good answer isn't really available - your page is updated using JavaScript and you'll need to use `selenium` or something similar for the webpage to complete loading and executing JavaScript before scraping.

The HTML your `s.get(link)` retrieves has all the information the JavaScript needs to dynamically populate the table, but not yet the actual data you want to scrape.

Since `requests` cannot run the JavaScript for you, you need to load it into an actual browser instead, for example a headless browser driven by a browser driver through `selenium`.

You can pick any flavour of browser, but for example, to get it to work with Firefox, you would download `gecko-driver` from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and put it in your project (say in a `bin` folder). Also install `selenium` with `pip install selenium` (assuming you use `pip`)

Your code would then be:

```
from os import environ
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# selenium needs the driver to be on the path, so adding that location
environ['path'] = f'bin;{environ["path"]}'

# set headless to False if you want to see what happens, 
# but to True for operation in the background
options = Options()
options.headless = True

# this expects `geckodriver.exe` to be on the path
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
# start loading the page
driver.get('https://cityofdavid.secure.force.com/?productId=01t0600000AE2dR&lang=en_us')

# make sure to keep waiting, until an element appears with the class `timer-message`
# note that this is different for each page, and may change - 
# just look for something that doesn't appear on the page until it is done loading
# or, if there is nothing like it, use some sort of delay like `time.sleep`
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'timer-message')))

# the below uses `driver.page_source` to stay close to your code
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
for item in soup.select("table.table > tbody > tr"):
    data = [i.text for i in item.select("td")]
    print(data)
```

Note that `driver` has its own methods for accessing elements in the live page  that may be nicer than using `bs4` - have a look at the documentation https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

If you prefer a fully automated solution and don't want to bundle a binary, you can use a library like [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to automate the installation process instead.

Note that you may find simpler solutions that suggest doing something like:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='bin/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

That still works, but `selenium` tells you that way of doing things is deprecated, so don't expect it to work indefinitely.

A final word of warning: most sites don't like their content being scraped. In some cases, dynamically loading their content is their way of attaining security through obscurity and the above allows you to circumvent this - make sure what you're doing is actually OK.

A more lightweight approach (which the site admin may or may not be OK with) would be to find out where the JS loads its data and load that directly. In the case of your page for example, the URL https://cityofdavid.secure.force.com/apexremote will load the data only as JSON, but requires you to provide the correct header and cookies, which may take some figuring out to get right (and possibly require you to hit an actual webpage first anyway, to get a session cookie). The suggested answer by @ManishShetty provides some insight on how to get started on that. If you just follow this link right here, you will be denied access.

The *best* way is always to check for an API and use that if it is available. If it isn't, follow the site's rules or break them at your own peril. Don't blame me if your IP gets black-listed - or worse.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the scrabbled data because the content is generated by Javascript
, to handle this you  need  to selenium or anything similar to get the Javascript data, Instead of request you can use selenium to get the page source & then continue with soup as you were

```
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://cityofdavid.secure.force.com/?productId=01t0600000AE2dR&lang=en_us')
time.sleep(5)
htmlSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, "lxml")
for item in soup.select("table.table > tbody > tr"):
    data = [i.text for i in item.select("td")]
    print(data)
```

Will return the below data you can use as required

```
['24/01/2022', '10:00', '11:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['24/01/2022', '12:00', '13:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['24/01/2022', '14:00', '15:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['24/01/2022', '16:00', '17:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['25/01/2022', '10:00', '11:00', '11', '\nSelect\n\n']
['25/01/2022', '12:00', '13:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['25/01/2022', '14:00', '15:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['25/01/2022', '16:00', '17:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['26/01/2022', '10:00', '11:00', '14', '\nSelect\n\n']
['26/01/2022', '12:00', '13:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['26/01/2022', '14:00', '15:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['26/01/2022', '16:00', '17:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['27/01/2022', '10:00', '11:00', '12', '\nSelect\n\n']
['27/01/2022', '12:00', '13:00', '11', '\nSelect\n\n']
['27/01/2022', '14:00', '15:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['27/01/2022', '16:00', '17:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['30/01/2022', '10:00', '11:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['30/01/2022', '12:00', '13:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['30/01/2022', '14:00', '15:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
['30/01/2022', '16:00', '17:00', '15', '\nSelect\n\n']
```